# ValueError: shapes (259,2) and (1,33) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

At a loss for what this error means, my data is too large to post but even a smaller version (say, 2 columns) gets a similar error. Here's the code:

```
X = regressions[[x for x in regressions.columns if 'prev' in x]]
Y = regressions['PTSN']
X = sm.add_constant(X)

model = sm.OLS(Y,X)
fitted = model.fit()

predictions = fitted.predict(x)

print(fitted.summary())
```

Both of Y and X have a length of 252 rows, Y contains 1 column and X contains 32 columns. How do i begin untangling this error? or what is the solution?

Comment: Hard to see the problem without MCVE but can you try `X = regressions[x for x in regressions.columns if 'prev' in x]` by removing one pair of extra `[ ]`

Comment: Does it raise in predict? What is the lower case `x` in predict? The x in predict needs to have the same kind of columns as X in the model. Show at least the relevant parts of the traceback. My guess is `x dot params` has shape mismatch because your `x` in predict is wrong.

Comment: Removing a set of brackets produces this error:

 X = regressions[x for x in regressions.columns if 'prev' in x]
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Josef AH!!! You are correct. It was the lowercase x. My tired eyes didn't notice it. Thank you for exposing my lack of attention to detail.